# NWConnection timeout

Tags: ios, swift, networking, tcp

this is my first post to the community, so please be patient ;-)

I am using Apples Network framework to build a TCP connection to a server. It locks like this:

```
let testConnection = NWConnection(host: NWEndpoint.Host(server!.serverAddress), port: NWEndpoint.Port(server!.serverPort)!, using: .tcp)
testConnection.stateUpdateHandler = ({ state in
        print("TCP state change to: \(state)")
        switch state {
        case .setup:
            break
        case .waiting(let error):
            print("Waiting Error \(error)")
            testConnection.cancel()
            break
        case .preparing:
            break
        case .ready:
            beginCommunication()
            break
        case .failed(let error):
            print("\(error)")
            break
        case .cancelled:
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    })
```

The serverAddress and serverPort is entered by the user. I want to test the connection. Now my problem is, that if the user is entering an invalid address / port combination (the service is not offered by the server). I stuck in the preparing state for quite a long time. After that I get to the waiting stage (with error message **POSIXErrorCode: Operation timed out**).

Is there any way to set the timeout for this first connection process ?

Thanks for your ideas

Comment: You would need to set up your own `Timer`. When you leave the `preparing` state, invalidate the timer. If the timer fires, call `cancel` or `forceCancel` on the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set connection timed out by NWProtocolTCP.Options

```swift
lazy var tcpOptions: NWProtocolTCP.Options = {
    let options = NWProtocolTCP.Options()
    options.connectionTimeout = 5 // connection timed out
    return options
}()

lazy var parames: NWParameters = {
    let parames = NWParameters(tls: nil, tcp: self.tcpOptions)
    if let isOption = parames.defaultProtocolStack.internetProtocol as? NWProtocolIP.Options {
        isOption.version = .v4
    }
    parames.preferNoProxies = true
    return parames
}()

lazy var connection: NWConnection = {
    let connection = NWConnection(host: "x.x.x.x", port: xxxx, using: self.parames)
    return connection
}()
```

When trigger the timed out event, the .waiting state will call back.

```
2021-08-30 23:05:17.xxxxxx+xxxx Demo[xxxx:xxxxxx] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [60: Operation timed out]
The connection is waiting for a network path change with: POSIXErrorCode: Operation timed out
```

reference from [Developer Fourms](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/662177?answerId=654424022#654424022)